# Windows 10 Custom Keyboard Layout Abbreviation

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout, language

I made a custom keyboard layout using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 and successfully installed it. However I do not know how to change the abbreviation that shows in the language bar on the taskbar. For example the default English US keyboard has "ENG" on one line and "US" underneath it, and the US International keyboard has "ENG" and "INTL". My custom layout only has "ENG" and nothing underneath. I have no idea where to look.

The screenshot shows it much more clearly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trying editing the text file manually.

```
KBD Layout01    "United States-International - Custom"

COPYRIGHT   "(c) 2020 Company"

COMPANY "Company"

LOCALENAME  "en-US"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found partial solve. You can use predefined name for layout. Name of layout also overrides.

[I set predefined name to custom layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM4QF.png) Here are 2 custom layouts. 2nd (RUT) with changed Layout ID.

Find in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\`
layout with preffered name. `Layout text` string help you.

In my case 10419 has

```
Layout Text - Russian Typewriter
Layout ID - 0008
```

Open your custom layout entry. They are at the end of layouts. My which I changed is a0010422.
Paste this Layout ID - 0008 and it is showed as 10419 entry - Russian typewriter. But actual layout is custom, only name changed.

In win7 you can assign custom icon to every layout. IDK why MS killed that feature.